# Does the shape of a tensor for an image affect the resulting output?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am representing images of size 100px by 100px, so I can have the shape `(None, 100, 100, 3)` or shape `(None, 10000, 3)`

I can't find any clear explanation on Google, however, will the following two tensors result in similar results?

1. `(None, 100, 100, 3)`
2. `(None, 10000, 3)`

I assume either is sufficient as I would have thought the neural network will still learn just as well if the image is in a single row, your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the 1st shape : `( 100 , 100 , 3 )`**

This is a 3 dimensional tensor. If you are working with Dense layers, they require two dimensional input. Yes, 1D Convolutional layers exist but they are reserved for totally different use cases.

A Convolutional layer would pass a kernel through definite strides and will gather spatial information. This kernel will then get pooled so that the information is retained but with lesser dimensions.

> Hence, the learning with this shape, would be far better as learning
>   of spatial features will take place. This is excellent for Image
>   Classification.

**For 2nd shape : `( 10000 , 3 )`**

This is 2 dimensional tensor and would work with 1D Convolutional layers and Dense layers.

1D Convolutions pass the kernel through only one straight line ( axis ). Also the features of the image would get aligned in a straight ( all the columns would get lined up ). This will destroy the features of the image.

> Hence, at last, an image is a 2D object a and must be kept in it's original dimension to facilitate learning. A 1D tensor has other uses like Text classification,  human activity recognition etc.